# Java JFrame: howto parse recursively through componets (i.e. if using JScrollPane)

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea, tablelayout

I'm using [TableLayout](https://tablelayout.dev.java.net/) for my swing GUI. Initially only some basic labels, buttons and text fields where required which I could later on access by:

```
public Component getComponent(String componentName) {
    return getComponent(componentName, this.frame.getContentPane());
}

private Component getComponent(String componentName, Component component) {
    Component found = null;

    if (component.getName() != null && component.getName().equals(componentName)) {
        found = component;
    } else {
        for (Component child : ((Container) component).getComponents()) {
            found = getComponent(componentName, child);

            if (found != null)
                break;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Unfortunately I ran into issues after using using `JScrollPane` to support scrolling in `JTextArea` and JTable's, which I did with:

```
JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
ta.setName("fooburg");
JScrollPane scr = new JScrollPane(ta);
frame.getContentPane().add(scr, "1, 1");  // EDIT: changed, tkx bruno
```

After suggestions, I've been able to access through `getComponent("fooburg")` the desired component (the version above is the final one). Many thanks to Dan and Bruno!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@bruno is right - you need to add the text pane to the frame's content pane.

Slightly OT: If you generally want to access every component in a hierarchy, you need something recursive - your current method will only print immediate child names:

```
void printNames(Component component) {
    System.out.println(component.getName());
    for (Component child : component.getComponents()) {
        printNames(child);
    }
}

void printFrameNamesComponents(JFrame frame) {
    printNames(frame.getContentPane());
}
```

(not tested, but something like this.)

Comment: Thank you Dan, I updated the function and implemented it as you suggested. It works fine for textfields & co, but not for components embedded in JScrollPane :-(

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the child to the JFrame's content pane instead:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(comp);
```

If you add your new component to JFrame directly, your code above never get's to it because you are only enumerating the components under `frame.getContentPane()`.